# Programming AppleScript Editor, Code

Tags: applescript

So far i have this but i want to make it to where the finder window will open as many times and the variable "amount" is set to

```
set volume 10
set amount to text returned of (display dialog "How many times?" default answer "More than 10")
tell application "Finder" to make new Finder window
repeat amount times
end repeat
```

If someone could help me would be much appreciated.

(Script is not done yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast answer:
Move the part you want to be repeated inside the repeat .. end repeat block:

```
set amount to text returned of (display dialog "How many times?" default answer "More than 10")
repeat amount times
    tell application "Finder" to make new Finder window
end repeat
```

Maybe you should check if the user really entered a numeric value and if it is greater than 10 in your next steps.

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: How can i find that out i have tried the "<" and ">" symbols?

Comment: Use a try - on error - end try block. 

`try
set amt_as_int to amount as integer
on error
return "Not a number"
end try`